# Cant make my script.js while it works on Codeacademy

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So I coded a counter using a javascript script in my html file (using Angular 2). Here are my two files (I'm not including the styles one).

pokehunted.component.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="displayCounter">
    <button class="box" onclick="modify_qty(1)"> 
        <p>Pikachu</p>
        <input type="image" src="../../assets/img/pikachu.png" /> 
    </button>
    <div class="counter">
        <label for="qty"><abbr title="Quantity">Rencontres</abbr></label>
        <input id="qty" value="0" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
function modify_qty(val) {
    var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
    var new_qty = parseInt(qty,10) + val;

    if (new_qty < 0) {
        new_qty = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById('qty').value = new_qty;
    return new_qty;
}
```

Problem is, I coded this on Codeacademy, and it worked perfectly. The objective was to create a div button that increments the counter below it. On Codeacademy it did, and in my project, the counter doesnt move.

Do you have an idea of what I am doing wrong ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not angular2 and your code works

Comment: this is vanilla javascript

Comment: Check your javascript path, where have you placed it ?

Comment: Those are just two files I use in my angular project. But if the code works why doesnt the counter change when I click on the button ?
Edit - The javascript is at the right location, the path is recognized by Visual studio code

Comment: Have you looked at the browser console for errors? The function works fine for me.

Comment: this code works fine

Comment: I do have a console error everytime i click on the button : 
Uncaught ReferenceError: modify_qty is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (chasse:1)
Chasse being the route to the actual page.

Comment: Okay, so, I guess I just dont know how it works. When I implement the script in this component (I took back all the <html> and <body> tags, it was just here for codeacademy), the script doesnt appear at all. I tried to initialize it in the index.html, and script.js appears in the console, but that's index.html who's written in the script.js. So, my script is never recognized as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I fixed it ! I had to put my script in my angular-cli.json instead of putting it in my HTML. I dont really know why I cant just use a  tag to do that, but it works that way. Here is the part I modified in my json :

```
"apps": [
  {
    "scripts": [
      "app/pokehunted/script.js"
    ],
  [...]
  }
]
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, but why are you putting this in an external script rather than a method within your component class.